# Network adapter driver must be uninstalled on every reboot, server 2016

Tags: drivers, network-adapter, device-manager, windows-server-2016

I have just set up a machine with Windows Server 2016 at home just to play with, I am not a sys admin.

Upon first boot, and any other restart the Intel 82578DC network adapter is in error and not working (code 10). All I need to do to make it work is uninstall the driver via device manager. Windows then apparently re installs it because network connection comes up right after that.

In event log the only relevant thing I can find (not knowing much about browsing eventlog) is a system event around the time I rebooted: "Intel 82578DC Gigabit Network Connection PROBLEM: "Unable to start the network adapter" ACTION: Install the latest driver from... [intel site]

I have downloaded intels driver installation tool, which claims there ARE NO intel network adapters on the machine. Device manager, once it is up and running, claims the device has the most up to date driver.

This DOES NOT happen on a restart. Just a full shut down and power back up.

I have no idea what to look at to resolve this though. My goal was to have this server off most of the time, and be able to turn it on and use remote desktop from my laptop rather than needing a monitor for it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

[Info Source:](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-code-10-errors-2623181/) https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-fix-code-10-errors-262318/

## What it might be

> "A Code 10 error is generated when Device Manager can't start the
>   hardware device, a situation usually caused by outdated or corrupted
>   drivers."

So, did you try completely removing and then installing the latest drivers from the intel site?

---

> "A device may also receive a Code 10 error if a driver generates an
>   error that Device Manager doesn't understand. In other words, a Code
>   10 error can sometimes be a very generic message indicating some kind
>   of unspecified driver or hardware problem."

Perhaps there is an issue other than drivers, physical or digital.

---

Looking at the downloads for the "*Intel® 82578DC Gigabit Ethernet PHY*" shows no drivers for windows server 2016, the latest OS versions supported seem to be *Windows 8* and *Windows Server 2008.* These drivers might not work correctly with Windows server 2016.

### Some Possible Solutions

- Rolling back the driver to a version older than what is in use.
- Removing or reconfigure the newly installed device. (reinstall)
- Trying a system restore. (Seeing as you "just set it up" you probably don't have any)
- Removing the drivers and then installing the official drivers from intel.
- Testing another PCI slot, perhaps that particular one isn't working correctly.
- If you have a copy of an older OS that has drivers made for it test that and see if the issue is gone. If it is the issue might be with Windows Server 2016 and the drivers not being compatible.